# Prevent timer from pausing when activity is in background

Tags: android, timer, android-activity

Contrary to what most people want, I want to prevent my timer from pausing while the activity is in the background. If this is not possible, is there a way I can achieve this?

Edit:
Basically, what I'm doing is incrementing a counter in a database every second. It is sort of critical that it doesn't skip an increment until the user stops the process himself.

Comment: So use a Service or an Alarm.

Comment: Some timers can stay active. I've noticed that single activity apps with a timer will continue to run a timer thread even after the app has gone to the background.

Comment: @Phil That is true, but only for a limited time on mine. It would run for about 5 minutes, then it will pause. It will resume when the activity is active again.

Comment: @EZFrag this is because simple timers are built around the concept of `Looper`s and `Handler`s which run on the UI thread. when your activity is destroyed (technically: detached from the looper), the timers cease to function. use a `Service` or `AlarmManager` just like A--C and Argyle said. use the latter if you want the timer to function even when the device is sleeping (~ its screen is turned off).

Comment: Are you suggesting that I keep the activity active using an alarm?